# Design of Databases in SQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, datatable

Creating a design of a database to include the following:
Type of Product 
Login in Table (W/ name and email)
Sales Table
Checkout Table

Must be in MySQL Workbench

I've connected to the server and unsure, do I write this in MySQL workplace and then update to myphpadmin?

No code as of yet- need an example of how to design a database

Eventually there will be need for web presence.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench, you can design the tables and relationships with an ERR Diagram if you want a visual way. You can then forward engineer the actual DDL for generating the tables and columns and output to a file. You can run said file on any mysql server whether that's locally on your personal computer or a server.

PHPAdmin let's you interact with the database in a similar way to create, update, or delete tables and columns.